# generating Random numbers in R without Decimal and changing to Numeric without change in value

Tags: r

Create a factor vector using 10 random numbers without decimals.
Convert the factor vector to numeric vector.
Compare 1st and 2nd vector element wise and store the comparison values ie (True or false) in another vector and display it.

```
vector1 <- factor(floor((runif(10,min=0,max=101))))
vector2 <- as.numeric(v1)
vector3 <- c()
i <- 1
  while(i<= 10)
{
    if(vector1[i]==vector2[i])
    {
        vector3[i] ="TRUE"

    }     else
        if(vector1[i]!=vector2[i])
        {
          vector3[i] = "FALSE"
        }
       i <- i+1    
 }
   vector3
```

TRUE, TRUE ,FALSE.......

Comment: The values are changed can someone please help me in t his

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/numeric) states:

> If x is a factor, `as.numeric` will return the underlying numeric (integer) representation, which is often meaningless as it may not correspond to the factor levels, see the ‘Warning’ section in [factor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/factor).

That warning states:

> The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same set of levels (in the same order). In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`.

Similar warnings and advice are given in this [R FAQ on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f).

So that's exactly what you should do to convert your factor vector to a numeric one:

```r
vector2 <- as.numeric(levels(vector1))[vector1]
```

To store the comparison results in another vector, you can just do:

```r
vector3 <- vector1 == vector2
```

Or if you are required to use a `for` loop to compare element-wise:

```r
vector3 <-c()
for (i in 1:length(vector1))
{
  vector3[i] <- vector1[i] == vector2[i]
}
```

You can see and run this code [here](https://repl.it/repls/ThunderousMealyFonts).

Comment: how do  i compare element wise  ? i tried this

for(i in 1:length(vector1))
{
  for(j in 1:length(vector2))
  {
    if(vector1[i]= vector2[j])
    {
      vector3[i] = "TRUE"
    }
     else
    {
      if(vector1[i]!=vector2[j])
        {
          vector3[i] = "FALSE"
       }
  
    }
      
  }
}

I am getting error

Comment: i tried this 
v1 <- factor(floor((runif(10,min=0,max=101))))
v2 <- as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]
v3 <- c()
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(i<= 10)
{
  while(j<=10)
  {
    if(v1[i]==v2[j])
    {
      v3[i] ="TRUE"
      
    }   else
    {
      v3[i] = "FALSE"
      
    }
    j <- j+1
  }
  i <- i+1    
}
v3

i am getting only one value in v3 , please help  .
thanks

Comment: @Ramco, try the code I put. What you are typing doesn't make sense. You don't need j, you are looping the same index position in both vectors. You only need i

Comment: Working
v1 <- factor(floor((runif(10,min=0,max=101))))
v2 <- as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]
v3 <- v1 == v2
print(v3)

Answer (score 1):

Working

```
v1 <- factor(floor((runif(10,min=0,max=101))))
v2 <- as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]
v3 <- v1 == v2
print(v3)
```

Comment: Clever approach. Could you add a few explaining remarks so that everybody can learn from it? Thanks.